# Linux: Moved `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so` and now SSH is dead

Tags: linux, debian, libc

The problem is basically already in the title: Because I wasn't able to upgrade `libc6` I did what the output told me to do: Remove (or move) `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so`

```
A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
  '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' and try again.
```

But right after executing that `mv` command, ssh is doing weird things such as:

```
~$ mv
-bash: /usr/bin/mv: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, I am in my home directory `~` but somehow Linux thinks I am in `/usr/bin/mv`. Any idea how I get back to "normal" via SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because the program interpreter (the glibc dynamic loader) can no longer be found. The upgrade error message was due to [bug #954915:  [libc6] upgrade fail: A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=954915). Its advice is incorrect, and following it breaks the system.

If you do not happen to have a statically linked collection of tools install (`busybox`, `sash`, `sln`), you will have to boot from rescue media and undo the move. You may be able to avoid that if you have an open program (such as an editor) running as root, which can make a copy of the dynamic loader in the expected location.

Comment: So in case I don't have an open program running as root, there is no way to fix this via SSH?

Comment: Not really. You need root privileges to fix this, and the programs that could give you root privileges (such as sudo) require the dynamic loader because they are not statically linked.

Answer (score -1):

The `mv` is under `/bin/mv` on Ubuntu, but you should check the `PATH` environment variable like `echo $PATH`.
Above error means `PATH` variable doesn't contain this `/usr/bin` path.
To add this path, please try to run this command on your terminal.
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`.
Also, you can check `mv` is available or not 
`which mv`

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin` didn't change anything

Comment: Please post your `echo $PATH` result